# Illegal StateException Error

Tags: android, database, kotlin, illegalstateexception

I recently migrated from Java to Kotlin and converted my app's code into kotlin code and published the changes.But now some users are reporting that there app is force stopping. But me and the tested devices are not facing the issue. When I checked the crashes page. It is showing this:

[image]

And this is the DatabaseHelper Class Code with line 1018

[image]

```
fun getNotes(sqlCommand: String): MutableList<Note> {
    val result = ArrayList<Note>()
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    Log.e(LOG, sqlCommand)
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlCommand, null)
    try {
        if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val note = Note()
                note.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))
                note.title = DataEncryption.encryptDecrypt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)))
                note.content = DataEncryption.encryptDecrypt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT)))
                note.updatedAt = Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UPDATED_AT)))
                note.color = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COLOR))
                note.favourite = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FAVOURITE))
                if (cursor.isNull(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCKSTATUS)))) {
                    note.lock_status = 0
                } else {
                    note.lock_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCKSTATUS))
                }
                note.reminderDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_DATE))
                note.reminderTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_TIME))
                if (cursor.isNull(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_STATUS)))) {
                    note.reminderStatus = 0
                } else {
                    note.reminderStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_STATUS))
                }
                note.noteCategoryTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CATEGORY_NOTE_TITLE))
                note.noteCategoryStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CATEGORY_NOTE_STATUS))
                note.checklist = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHECKLIST))
                if (cursor.isNull(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_REPEAT_STATUS)))) {
                    note.alarmRepeatStatus = 0
                } else {
                    note.alarmRepeatStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM_REPEAT_STATUS))
                }
                result.add(note)
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return result
}
```

Someone please help me with a solution. Help is high appreciated.

Comment: Please post as text instead of images.

Comment: Added Text of the Method where the error is occuring.

Comment: Error could be when you are searching column that doesn't exist in cursor. Post your command string and `KEY_*` variables values.